# position: relative causes anchors to be unclickable

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I was fiddling around with a web site I am developing, attempting to fix some odd IE7 bugs, since this is an internal project and IE7 is the standard browser. I ended up adding "position: relative" to correct a couple IE-specific layout problems, but I seem to have made things worse in FF/Chrome (I consider myself more of a systems programmer, but my current responsibilities involve more of a web focus unfortunately).

The specific problem is that the "position: relative" elements ended up making some of my links, which were floated to the right, unclickable. I've created a simple test page that I hope will explain this better than I can with words: http://jsfiddle.net/gBchZ/.

I will sort through this mess eventually, but I was hoping that someone could explain the reason behind my links getting hidden behind the position: relative elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without having the link of the site is difficult to tell exactly what is wrong. But in any case, a solution could be to use `z-index` for the parent of `a`. For example `z-index:100`. Keep in mind that `z-index` works only with positioned elements, so you can use `position:relative`.

**Demo based on your example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gBchZ/3/

Comment: +1 for reminding that z-index only works with positioned elements.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `.content` `div`s are covering the right-box (in your demo). If you add a `margin-right` to those divs the `a` becomes 'reachable:'

```
.content
{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gBchZ/2/)

You could also use `position: absolute;` to make the `a` element appear 'higher' in the `z-index`, though this becomes rather complex:

```
#rightBox
{
    background-color: green;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -20px .5em .5em .5em;
    padding: .5em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gBchZ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

[@David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235073/position-relative-causes-anchors-to-be-unclickable/5235146#5235146)’s correct in that the `position: relative` on the `.content` items is giving them a z-index, meaning they’re “on top” of the link you’ve floated to the right.

I think a better solution though is to add `position: relative;` to the link you’ve floated right as well, and give it a z-index higher than `.content`:

```
#rightBox
{
    ...
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.content
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/gBchZ/6/